# FFMPEG Concat Audio at timestamp

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm attempting to concat two mp3 audio files (fileA and fileB) at a specific timestamp for a specific duration only. Such that the audio in file A is replaced with that in file B for the aforementioned duration. Thus the end result should be:

FileA - FileB(for duration) - FileA

Can this be done with FFMPEG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Assuming both files have the same sampling rate and channel count, you would create a text file like this,

```
file a.mp3
outpoint 45
file b.mp3
inpoint 0
outpoint 23
file a.mp3
inpoint 68
```

and then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i text -c copy out.mp3
```

The sequence of the output will be A START-45 + B 0-23 + A 68-END

Comment: Absolutely fantastic does exactly what I need. After posting the question, I did manage to arrive at a solution using the filter-complex concat demuxer, however this resulted in the file being re-encoded which was very inefficient.