# What FFMPEG command will overlay 2 audio files at a specific timestamp?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

What ffmpeg command will create a new audio file from overlaying 2 audio files at a specific, non-zero timestamp?

For example:

1. Imagine 2 audio files, File A and File B, that both last for 10 seconds.
2. I run an ffmpeg command on them both that creates a new file, whose structure is as follows:
3. File A plays from 0:00 to 0:05.
4. From 0:05 to 0:10, both File A and File B play simultaneously.
5. From 0:10 to 0:15, only File B plays, and then this new merged & overlaid audio file ends.

What ffmpeg command will accomplish this?

My current command will switch between File A and File B at the right timestamps, but from 0:05 to 0:10, it will only play File B, and not File B also:

`ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp3`

mylist.txt:

```
file input1.mp3
outpoint 45
file input2.mp3
inpoint 0
outpoint 23
file input1.mp3
inpoint 68
```

For reference, here are similar forum questions I'm studying:

[FFMPEG Concat Audio at timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920025/ffmpeg-concat-audio-at-timestamp)

[FFmpeg add multiple audio files to video at specific points](https://superuser.com/questions/762886/ffmpeg-add-multiple-audio-files-to-video-at-specific-points)

Thanks!

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1092291

Comment: Thank you so much @Gyan, I will test your referenced post's solution tomorrow and let you know the results.

On another note, I just want to say how impressive it has been reading many of your  posts on this site— I noticed you really are a superuser for ffmpeg on here, and I just want to give you at least one person's opinion about your accomplishments! For real not fishing for more help here (or anything at all like that), but the amount of insight you have into ffmpeg was the only thing that made me think my requested command was possible in the first place. Seriously, you are the man!

Comment: Hey Gyan, it's almost working; this is my current command: `ffmpeg -y -i ${fullSong} -i ${overlapper} -filter_complex "[1]adelay=${songLengthInMs}|${overlapInMs}[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" ${finalSong}`. The problem is that the command assumes that the 2nd file is stereo, but actually both input files are mono. But when I try to use a command that assumes they're both mono, there's no overlap, & the files are just played one after the other: `ffmpeg -y -i ${fullSong} -i ${overlapper} -filter_complex "[1]adelay=${songInMs}|${overlapInMs}[b]; [0][b]amix=2" ${finalSong}` Any ideas?

Comment: I got it working Gyan! Thanks so much: `ffmpeg -y -i ${fullSong} -i ${overlapper} -filter_complex "[1]adelay=${Ns}|${Ns}[b]; [0][b]amix=2" ${finalSong}`, where Ns = songInMs = overlapInMs. The problem was that I was not understanding the syntax for the adelay command correctly, how each value between the pipes is the delay for audio channels in order. Thanks again! I'll mark your comment as correct if you turn it into a post :)